# file system limit storage website azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a website running on windows azure. The File System Storage Limit is 10GB and my applications is going to exceed the limit. How can I increase the capacity of the File System Storage?? I am using a website with a MySQL Database and reserved web site mode.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you could increase this quota. One thing you could look into is storing some of the stuff in Blob Storage instead of storing them in the file system. That way you're not impacted by the 10 GB storage limitation of Windows Azure Websites.

Answer (score 2):

The storage capacity is determined by what plan you are on.  App Service (formerly Azure Websites) currently has Free, Shared, Basic, Standard, and Premium plans with 1 GB, 1 GB, 10 GB, 50 GB, and 500 GB of storage respectively. Note that this capacity is shared by all the websites hosted on the same VM.  See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/ for details.

If an application needs more than what you are allotted, using some other storage, such as Blob Storage is a good option to look at and will probably be cheaper than upgrading the plan.

Answer (score 1):

Just a point of note here - if you do decide to add a blob storage account and reference files (like large videos, images, documents etc.) from your website... the container will need to be set as "**Public**".

Comment: Hi @tripledad99  Welcome to SO.  If you add Comments under comments it makes it easier to find complete answers

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas if MySQL is running on Windows (you didn't specify the OS)...

- Call the Microsoft Azure support team (free call) and ask for an upgrade on storage
- Create a second Azure storage account, and use the Windows DiskManager to merge the drives together.